# Prestashop 1.7.0.2 Server responded with 500 code when trying to upload product image

Tags: product, prestashop-1.7

I am getting server responded with 500 code when i try to upload product image.I initially installed prestashop 1.7.0.2 on my localhost and later moved to online .But after that i cannot uppload image.Its working fine on my xampp server localhost.:Please help

Comment: Any help guys.... I am stuck here

Comment: Enable debug mode, tell us what's the error

Answer (score 0):

please try to switch on the ps_mod_dev in config/defines.inc.php
it will show the error text.